# Symfony2: How to ressource a routing file in xml

Tags: xml, symfony, routes, yaml

in routing.yml I can ressource other routing configs with:

```
AcmeTestBundle:
resource: "@AcmeTestBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"
prefix:   /
```

How does the same config look in XML?

I tried:

```
<route id="AcmeTestBundle">
    <default key="_ressource">AcmeTestBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml</default>
</route>
```

But this doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the official manual

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#including-external-routing-resources

There you can click on the tab named "XML"

```
<!-- app/config/routing.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <import resource="@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml" />
</routes>
```

Comment: Thank ya, didn't found it the first:

<import resource="@AcmeHelloBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml" prefix="/admin" />